# 2nd external display renders whites as bright yellow

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, color

I have two external Dell monitors running through a Thunderbolt 3 dock to my  15" MacBook Pro. On the 2nd one that I connected, all pure white colors show as a very vivid and bright yellow, much like a highlighter. No other color is affected, and off whites render fine.

Whats odd is that this monitor has this issue regardless of how I connect it to the laptop. Its broken via dock, or via direct DP to TB3 cable. It also has the issue while being the only monitor connected. The original monitor does not have the issue regardless of how I connect it.

This would imply a hardware issue with the monitor BUT I have confirmed the monitor works correctly on a windows laptop. Whats also odd is there's a split second after login that the colors are correct, before they go yellow. This also suggests the monitor hardware is fine.

Both monitors are running in forced RGB mode, but this did not correct the issue. 
PRAM reset also had no impact.

If I go into color calibration for the monitor, everything is fine so long as the target white is below 6500k. 6499k is fine, but the moment I raise it to 6500k (which is the default) the whites snap to highlighter yellow. They remain so for any value higher than 6500k.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?

Comment: Just wondering, since your workaround is to calibrate the color to have a target white of 6499k instead of the 6500k, is there a reason why that's a problem in terms of your solution? Or are you happy with that, but just curious if someone else has come across the same thing?

Comment: Mostly just curious at this point. When I originally asked the question I had not found that workaround. But now Id say its fine.

Comment: In that case you could remove the workaround from your question and actually add it as an answer to your own question. In time you'll even be able to accept it as the correct answer, but at least in the meantime it may help other users and also earn you some more reputation on the site. :)

Answer (score 2):

My current workaround is to calibrate the color to have a target white of 6499k.

This can be done under Display Settings -> Color -> Calibrate

Comment: I turned on my MBP today and had the exact same issue.  Thanks for the workaround! I'm assuming this is a problem with my video card but this at least gets me by for now.